# Allure-kotlin via gradle doesn't generate reports

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-emulator, allure

Could someone help me with the issue? I added in my project allure-kotlin for androidTests, and when I run them via command line: `./gradlew connectedEnvstageDebugAndroidTest` folder "allure-results" in the android emulator doesn't exist.
Also, I created this folder manually and ran it again results were the same.

**BUT**, when I run any test via IntelliJ Idea (via "run" button), folder generating and report exists. And if I'll run tests via command line report will be generated as well, but just after when I'll run a test via the "run" button.

Could someone help me with it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you get `connectedEnvstageDebugAndroidTest` this option in your gradle pane on the right of you screen

Comment: @Narendra_Nath what do you mean? It's my flavor that I'm using. Tests running but reports are not creating :(. Or do I understand wrong your question?